# unit test in DAO's save method

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I wrote a unit test to test the save method of DAO, I'm sure my save method works, however, when I running my unit test it ran into this error:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: row count (table=RECONCILIATION_OBJECT_HANDLER) expected:<[4]> but was:<[3]>
```

here's my unit test code:

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
@ExpectedDatabase(value="classpath:/expectedTable/expectedReconciliationHandler.xml",table="RECONCILIATION_OBJECT_HANDLER")
public void testsaveSingleHandler() {
    ReconciliationObjectHandler handler = new ReconciliationObjectHandler();
    handler.setObjectName("employee");
    handler.setHandler("NewHandler");
    dao.saveSingleHandler(handler);
}
```

here's my expected results:

```
<RECONCILIATION_OBJECT_HANDLER id="0"
                            OBJECT_NAME="employee"
                            HANDLER="FieldNameHandler" />
<RECONCILIATION_OBJECT_HANDLER id="1"
                            OBJECT_NAME="employee"
                            HANDLER="PickListHandler" />
<RECONCILIATION_OBJECT_HANDLER id="2"
                            OBJECT_NAME="employee"
                            HANDLER="SimpleHandler" />
<RECONCILIATION_OBJECT_HANDLER id="3"
                            OBJECT_NAME="employee"
                            HANDLER="NewHandler" />
```

-----------------update---------------------------------------------

I realize I don't need to add rollback annotation, and I need to offer all the column information for result comparison, however, everytime I run unit test the INSERT operation will make the auto increment of column "id" resulting the "id" fireld will not matching the expected results in the xml files, how can I ignore compare column "id"? 
now the error message is:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: value (table=RECONCILIATION_OBJECT_HANDLER, row=3, col=id) expected:<[3]> but was:<[12]>
```

Comment: after deleting annotation "@Transaction" and "@Rollback" I got another error:ComparisonFailure: column count (table=RECONCILIATION_OBJECT_HANDLER, expectedColCount=3, actualColCount=4) expected:<[HANDLER, [id, OBJECT_NAME]]> but was:<[HANDLER, [ID, OBJECT_NAME, SEQ]]>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution by reading the documentation:
[Spring Test DBUnit](http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/)

I can choose assertionMode=DatabaseAssertionMode.NON_STRICT in the annotation @ExpectedDatabase and then omit columns that I don't want.